# Update Newtonsoft.Json.dll in the GAC to login to Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2015, gac

I recently downloaded Visual Studio 2015 to build an SSRS report for dynamics 365.
However, when I try to sign into my account after the trial expiry date I get the following error message:

Method not found: 'Void Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonDictionaryContract.set_PropertyNameResolver(System.Func`2<System.String,System.String>)'.

[This was the only forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/0500d1ce-22ad-491c-b4d0-f388edfb37b1/method-not-found-error-when-trying-to-sign-into-my-microsoft-account-thru-visual-studio-2013?forum=visualstudiogeneral) I could find the issue on which suggested the Newtonsoft.Json.dll in the GAC was out of date.

Would anyone be able to provide guidance on updating this DLL? I'm not familiar with the process and what is required to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a product code I found online that let me bypass the login.

https://visualstudioproductkeys.wordpress.com/2017/10/14/microsoft-visual-studio-2015-product-keys/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).